# Recommendation for an OS X (or iPhone) work timing application?

Tags: macos, iphone, productivity, time-management

I've checked out [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/917/time-tracking-applications), but it refers to something a little different.

I would like an OS X app that is like a stopwatch with multiple timers. So if I have five different project and I start working on project "A" I can start that clock and then stop it and start the project "B" clock, etc.

The reason I want this is so that I can get a more accurate sense of how I spend my time throughout the day. My ambition is to use this knowledge to increase my productivity.

An iPhone app would also be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating several I settled on [Harvest](http://www.getharvest.com/).

Answer (score 2):

[iBiz](http://www.iggsoftware.com/ibiz/) and [Billings](http://www.billingsapp.com/) are both OS X apps that do time tracking all the way through to billing and invoicing, so they might be a bit heavy if you just want a simple app just to track time.

If you're doing freelancing work though, they're probably perfect.

Answer (score 0):

For the longest time, I used Toggl (http://www.toggl.com/) for tracking time spent working on small projects.

Answer (score 0):

[Eternity](http://komorian.com/eternity.html)

I looked through about 10 of them and I though this was the best. The others were either missing something or were overly complex. You just hit start for the task and you end up with a summary by day, week, or month.